# NSZombie on ios5 device to solve message sent to deallocated instance

Tags: ios, xcode, automatic-ref-counting, instruments, nszombie

It seems that NSZombie can only be enabled in the instruments if the program is on the simulator. 
I did NSZombie on Xcode and it tells me that this message sent to the deallocated instance happens in my video taking class, which is not supported on the simulator. Therefore I am unable to trace the instance which has been deallocated...

Is there any ideas in which i can find out which instance is being deallocated when I must use the device to make it happen? I'm using iOS5 with ARC..

Thank you so much in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Guys this is  really help full tool login install and use as per instruction this tool gives exact line no where there is error its been used in my organization  http://www.crashlytics.com/

Comment: join this fb group and make a help full community there as well thanks http://www.facebook.com/groups/360017687365706/